# Understanding srcset width values

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, srcset

I'm trying to understand how srcset width values work, but the basic example I have is throwing me off.

Given the code below, I expect the large image to display when the viewport is > 600px. However, it actually changes at 784px. I'm not sure why this is.

```
<!-- image changes to large variant at 784px instead of the expected 1024px -->
<img
  src="small.jpg"
  srcset="small.jpg 600w,
          large.jpg 1024w"
  alt="A test image">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Chrome uses a geometric mean to choose between two image candidates. So it still uses the 600 image because 1024 is too big and therefore switches.

In an upcoming release Chrome will always switch to the higher image, if you have a low density device. On other devices Chrome will still use a a median.

Comment: Thanks so much, Alexander. Was really tripping me up, but that makes sense!